# MessageFormat.format() with named parameters

Tags: java, comparative-review, formatting

I was looking for how to use `MessageFormat.format()` in Java with named parameters, as a similar option exists in Python, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286648/named-placeholders-in-string-formatting). Some functions are presented there, although they use internal cycles and StringBuilder, and apparently they can fall into infinite loops (comments there suggest that, and it makes sense).

[Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295004/1157100) (potential infinite loop):

> ```
> public static String format(String str, Map<String, Object> values) {
>
>     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
>
>     for (Entry<String, Object> entry : values.entrySet()) {
>
>         int start;
>         String pattern = "%(" + entry.getKey() + ")";
>         String value = entry.getValue().toString();
>
>         // Replace every occurence of %(key) with value
>         while ((start = builder.indexOf(pattern)) != -1) {
>             builder.replace(start, start + pattern.length(), value);
>         }
>     }
>
>     return builder.toString();
> }
> ```

[Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2287426/1157100) (infinite loop removed):

> ```
> public static String dictFormat(String format, Hashtable<String, Object> values) {
>     StringBuilder convFormat = new StringBuilder(format);
>     Enumeration<String> keys = values.keys();
>     ArrayList valueList = new ArrayList();
>     int currentPos = 1;
>     while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
>         String key = keys.nextElement(),
>         formatKey = "%(" + key + ")",
>         formatPos = "%" + Integer.toString(currentPos) + "$";
>         int index = -1;
>         while ((index = convFormat.indexOf(formatKey, index)) != -1) {
>             convFormat.replace(index, index + formatKey.length(), formatPos);
>             index += formatPos.length();
>         }
>         valueList.add(values.get(key));
>         ++currentPos;
>     }
>     return String.format(convFormat.toString(), valueList.toArray());
> }
> ```

And the question is, why not something simpler? Why is there an internal cycle?
Here my option (which probably has some issue I'm not aware of).

```
public static String format(String str, Map<String, String> values) {

    String finalString = str;

    // validation input string
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return finalString;

    // validate parameters
    } else if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : values.entrySet()) {

        String pattern = "%(" + entry.getKey() + ")";
        String value = entry.getValue();

        // Replace every occurrence of %(key) with value
        finalString = finalString.replace(pattern, value);
    }

    return finalString;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Performing string substitutions using multiple passes is almost always the wrong approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139572/9357), and leads to bugs.  If one of the values happens to be a string that looks like a `%(key)`, then all sorts of unpredictable things could happen, including various [uncontrolled format string attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string)!

Therefore, the string replacements must be done in a single pass of the format string.  I recommend doing it using a regular expression.

Furthermore, your method provides no escape mechanism, in case you need to specify a literal `%(blah)` in the format string.  In Java, it would be customary to use backslash as an escape character.

### Suggested solution

This solution uses [`Matcher.replaceAll(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)), which was introduced in Java 9, to provide each substitution text via a callback.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NamedFormatter {
    private static final Pattern RE = Pattern.compile(
        "\\\\(.)" +         // Treat any character after a backslash literally 
        "|" +
        "(%\\(([^)]+)\\))"  // Look for %(keys) to replace
    );

    private NamedFormatter() {}

    /**
     * Expands format strings containing <code>%(keys)</code>.
     *
     * <p>Examples:</p>
     *
     * <ul>
     * <li><code>NamedFormatter.format("Hello, %(name)!", Map.of("name", "200_success"))</code> → <code>"Hello, 200_success!"</code></li>
     * <li><code>NamedFormatter.format("Hello, \%(name)!", Map.of("name", "200_success"))</code> → <code>"Hello, %(name)!"</code></li>
     * <li><code>NamedFormatter.format("Hello, %(name)!", Map.of("foo", "bar"))</code> → <code>"Hello, %(name)!"</code></li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * @param fmt The format string.  Any character in the format string that
     *            follows a backslash is treated literally.  Any
     *            <code>%(key)</code> is replaced by its corresponding value
     *            in the <code>values</code> map.  If the key does not exist
     *            in the <code>values</code> map, then it is left unsubstituted.
     *
     * @param values Key-value pairs to be used in the substitutions.
     *
     * @return The formatted string.
     */
    public static String format(String fmt, Map<String, Object> values) {
        return RE.matcher(fmt).replaceAll(match ->
            match.group(1) != null ?
                match.group(1) :
                values.getOrDefault(match.group(3), match.group(2)).toString()
        );
    }
}
```